# react-flux application error - unable to find the function even if it's defined

Tags: reactjs-flux

I have a react component - coursePage.js

```
function getCourseInitState(){
    return {
    courses: CourseStore.getAllCourses()//courseStore is required in script
    };
}

var Courses = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return getCourseInitState();
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
                <div>
                <h1> Course </h1>
                <CourseList courses={this.state.courses} />
                </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Action file -courseAction

```
var CourseAction = {
CourseList: function(){
    var courseList = CourseApi.getAllCourses();

    Dispatcher.dispatch({
        actionType: ActionTypes.COURSE_INITIALIZE,
        courseList: courseList
    });
}
```

Store File - courseStore

```
    var CourseStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {

    addChangeListener: function(callback){
        this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
    },

    removeChangeListener: function(callback){
        this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
    },

    emitChange: function(){
        this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
    },

    getAllcourses: function(){  //here is the function define
        return _courses;
    },

    getCourseById: function(id){
        return _.find(_courses, {id: id});
    }
});

    Dispatcher.register(function(action){
        switch(action.actionType){
            case ActionTypes.COURSE_INITIALIZE:
                _courses = action.CourseList;
                CourseStore.emitChange();
            break;
        }
    });

module.exports = CourseStore;
```

- in console I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: CourseStore.getAllCourses is not a function"

I don't want to call api directly in my coursePage.js so I find this way of initialising the page but it is not working.

(Please note - I am new to this) As per my recent learning Action file must always call API and send the request to State. I can load with help of componentWillMount function. But, I wanted to solve with this.If not wrong, then it is more neat and preferable way of implementing?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo -> `getAllcourses` in the Store and in the Component you call `getAllCourses`

```
getAllCourses: function(){  //Should be getAllCourses instead of getAllcourses
    return _courses;
},
```